# what does "elts" stands for in nginx source code

Tags: nginx

I'm reading nginx source code, and I found `elts` is in many data structure declaration, such as:

```
struct ngx_array_s {
void *elts;
ngx_uint_t nelts;
/* some members are omited */
}
```

From the code, I know `elts` is the address of the array that is used to store elements. But I wonder what `elts` stands for. After googling a bit. and feel like maybe it stands for element start ([reference](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/ELT)). Is it right, or what is the exact words it stands for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"elements". Your googling was accurate.